# Temporary autoincrement column on Delphi + Zeos, multiple queries failed?

Tags: mysql, delphi, zeos

Let's say I have very simple table :

```
CREATE TABLE Bands (Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL) ENGINE = INNODB;
INSERT INTO Bands VALUES ('Hammerfall'), ('Helloween'), ('Haggard'),
                         ('Therion'), ('Tarja');
```

And run a query :

```
SET @i := 0;
SELECT @i := @i + 1 No, Name
FROM Bands
WHERE Name LIKE 'H%'
```

On HeidiSQL and PhyMyAdmin it runs well :

```
1 Hammerfall
2 Helloween
3 Haggard
```

But in Delphi 2009 failed with error

> SQL Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @i := @i + 1 No, Name FROM Bands WHERE Name LIKE 'H%'

I write the query in TZQuery.SQL box, *Query*.SQL.Text and *Query*.SQL.Add(). All failed.

Is there a way to run that query?

The real query I will use is to join some 20+ columns tables to generate some reports.
But I cant even make this tiny thing works ~__~

Comment: I can't test it now but I suspect the problem lies in the fact that you are issuing 2 sql commands in the same execution of the query. Try leaving only the `select` sentence and setting the `@i` with `myquery.ParamByName('i').AsInteger`

Comment: as fas as you are using ':' in your SQL I'm pretty shure it's the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103180/adodb-component-causes-access-violation-on-win7-server-2008. Try to set ParamCheck to false.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the commenters the problem is two-fold.

1. You cannot execute 2 statements in a single SQL (this is a protection against SQL injection).
2. You cannot use `:` if `TQuery.CheckParams = true`.

Note that it's a bad idea to have InnoDB tables with no explicit primary keys.
The problem is that if you don't create a PK, MySQL will create a hidden PK for you and that will slow join performance way down.

If you want InnoDB to run efficient it's advisable to create

```
integer primary key auto_increment
```

fields in every table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but :

1. I don't need protection at this level, as its created on the fly and don't need user writing.

2. Set it to False, still doesn't work.

---

Yes I know its bad idea, but its just a sample, I've cut down everything. What I need is selecting record and make it an incremental order list, those values will be on report on the far left.